# object quantity from same class

Tags: php

```
class a {

}


$obj1 = new a();
$obj2 = new a();
$obj3 = new a();
```

May be very trite, but... how many object creates this code?

I think, may be this code greates only 1 object in this line `$obj1 = new a();` and `$obj2` and `$obj3` just indicate on an already created object?

I am wrong?

Comment: You're completely wrong. Why would a `new` statement give you an already created object instead of a **new** one?

Comment: You're completely missing what makes OOP OOP. The difference between terms "class" and "object" is fundamental.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code will create three distinct objects, and each variable will reference a different one.  `new` *always* constructs a new object instance.